# MYSQL - MATCH AGAINST score value = 0 but is >0 in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, match-against

I have 2 similar DB, on 2 servers.
If i try to execute this request one each one :

```
SELECT u.lastname, MATCH (u.lastname) AGAINST ('Rod*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
FROM user u
WHERE MATCH (u.lastname) AGAINST ('Rod*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0 ;
```

On the first server, it give me results with a numeric value as score of the match against.

One the second one, I got the same results, so the where clause is really applied, but the score is always = to 0.

Do you have any idea ? I guess it could be a specific conf of mysql... but I don't know which one to check.

Thanks very much

Comment: You definitely shouldn't match both in select and where.

Comment: It's just an example... I need to select the Match Against if I want to know his value.
This request leads me to the same issue : 
SELECT  u.lastname, MATCH (u.lastname) AGAINST ('Rod*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score FROM user u HAVING score > 0

Answer (score 2):

Select from a derived table:

```
SELECT lastname, score FROM (
SELECT u.lastname, MATCH (u.lastname) AGAINST ('Rod*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
FROM user u 
) as derivedTable WHERE score <> 0 ORDER BY score DESC;
```